# Какой способ лучше использовать с DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom

Какой из способов ниже более эффективен или в чем разница между этими двумя способами, которые делают одно и тоже? Какой из способов более предпочтителен и как делать не стоит?

1. В body отправляется html-код и в нем отыскиваются объекты:

```js
const html = document.body;
html.innerHTML = `
  <div class="sample">
    <div class="one"></div>
  </div>`;
const one = html.querySelector('.one');
one.textContent = 'hello';
```

2. Создавать объекты в js-коде и присоединять их:

```js
    const sample = document.createElement('div');
    sample.classList.add('sample');
    const one = document.createElement('div');
    one.classList.add('one');
    one.textContent = 'hello';
    sample.appendChild(one);
    document.body.appendChild(sample);
```

Comment: Вы думаете существует несколько способов создания про100 так? Один хуже другой лучше.

Comment: Оба варианта используются повсеместно. Разница в том что первый может быть подготовлен на сервере а второй только на клиенте

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946656/advantages-of-createelement-over-innerhtml#:~:text=As%20for%20performance%3A%20InnerHTML%20is,quirksmode%20benchmark%20provided%20by%20%40Pointy.

Comment: https://qna.habr.com/q/620207

Comment: Речь идет о клиентской части, на строне веб-браузера (клиента) какой из способов предпочитетелен. использовать querySelector, как мне кажется, весьма затратно, с другой стороны, второй способ веьсма будет громоздким, если будет много вложений.

Comment: https://coderoad.ru/2946656/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-createElement-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4-innerHTML

Comment: Тема давно разобранная.

Comment: Благодарю за ссылку на хабр, именнно там более раскрыли вопрос.

Comment: За последнюю ссылку также отдельная благодарность. Вопрос был про квериселектор, а оказалось, не там искал. Спасибо. Последняя ссылка раскрыла вопрос.